# TSlint Warning: deprecation atob is deprecated: Use `Buffer.from(data, 'base64')` instead

Tags: node.js, tslint

I have this warning when run lint on my project:

> deprecation  atob is deprecated: Use `Buffer.from(data, 'base64')` instead.

I´m trying to solve this warning by replace this line:

```
return JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]));
```

with the suggested solution showed in the console:

```
return JSON.parse(Buffer.from(token.split('.')[1],"base64"));
```

However, when debugging it shows the following error
[image]

How can i solve this problem? I´m using node 14!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed after changing:

> declare const Buffer: { from: (arg0: string, arg1: string) => string; };

to

> import { Buffer } from 'buffer';